# angularjs: resolve value from key pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any easy way to find a key in array and return its value instead of the key with angularjs (maybe by using expressions)?

right now, i do something like this:

```
vm.topics = [{id:1,value:"a"} , {id:2,value:"b"} , {id:3,value:"c"}];
vm.tickets= [{topic:2,summary:"summary 1"} , {topic:1,summary:"summary 2"}];
vm.getTopicName = function (id) {
    for (int t=0 ; t<vm.topics.length ; t++)
        if (vm.topics[t].id == id)
            return vm.topics[t].value;
    return id;
};
```

and in html part:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in vm.tickets">
  <td>{{vm.getTopicName(item.topic)}}</td>
  <td>{{item.summary}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there anything like

```
<td>{{item.topic | id as value in vm.topics}}</td>
```

Funny example, but i think it shows the point.

**--- UPDATE ---**

as @jantimon mentioned in comments, one way would be to change list to an object of real key pairs and simplify everything:

```
vm.topics1 = {};
for (var i=0; i < vm.topics.length; i++) {
  var t = vm.topics[i];
  vm.topics1[t.id] = t.value;
}
```

and HTML simply changes to:

```
<td>{{vm.topics1(item.topic)}}</td>
```

Comment: Why is your Id not the an object id? like `vm.topics = {1: a, 2:b, 3:c}` this would allow you to do sth like `topics[item.topic]`

Comment: This is a simplified example. the real application call each array with ajax and server side response is a list of objects.

Comment: that sounds wrong ;) you could still use the same way as long as the ids are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you use two different arrays and from your comment (ajax call) I would create new array in Service that *merges* `topics` and `tickets`, something like:

```
[... ,
 {
  topic:2,
  summary:"summary 1",
  ticket_value: "b"
 },
... ]
```

So controller should only draw it (without additional logic). This way will reduce watchers from your `ng-repeat` loop and you don't need to call *(rebuild)*  `getTopicName()`

**This is a right way I think,**

---

To simplify your example, if you use [Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) library, you can write:

```
 <td>{{topics[_.findIndex(topics, {id: item.topic})].value}}</td>
```

Demo in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7qky7f5/)</kbd>

*HTML*

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in tickets"> 
    <td>{{topics[_.findIndex(topics, {id: item.topic})].value}}    </td>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
$scope._ = _;

$scope.topics = [{id:1,value:"a"} , {id:2,value:"b"} , {id:3,value:"c"}];

$scope.tickets = [{topic:2,summary:"summary 1"} , {topic:1,summary:"summary 2"}];
```

---

**As a side note, try to avoid calling methods from HTML like:

```
<td>{{vm.getTopicName(item.topic)}}</td>
```

Comment: Won't that become slow?

Comment: @jantimon you mentioned a good point, I prefer to manage data in Services and do not in Controllers. See 1st part of answer

Comment: the answer Maxim gave was exactly what i was looking for. tickets list changes frequently. i preferred not adding them each time new tickets arrived (expecially when there is 3 or 4 topics max), so i will go with @jantimon 's solution.